# Know the number of the corner using cornerHarris

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I know the number of the corners that are calculated by cornerHarris ? The function I wrote is as follows :

```
    ...
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    int thresh = 160;
    Mat dst, dst_norm, dst_norm_scaled;
    dst = Mat::zeros( img.size(), CV_32FC1 );

    // Detector parameters
    int blockSize = 2;
    int apertureSize = 3;
    double k = 0.04;

    // Detecting corners
    cornerHarris( gray, dst, blockSize, apertureSize, k, BORDER_DEFAULT );

    // Normalizing
    normalize( dst, dst_norm, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_32FC1, Mat() );
    convertScaleAbs( dst_norm, dst_norm_scaled );
```

Answer (score 0):

`cornerHarris` does not calculate a specific amount of corners. It creates a new image `dst` that has the same size of your original image `gray`. You define a threshold value that from this value above you can find the corners. You will have more corners if you define your threshold to be smaller.
In your case you can find the corners for a predefined value of `thresh` like this:

```
for( int j = 0; j < dst_norm.rows ; j++ ){ 
    for( int i = 0; i < dst_norm.cols; i++ ){
        if( (int) dst_norm.at<float>(j,i) > thresh ){
                /* Whatever your would like to do with that corner */
        }
    }
}
```

See this [Harris Corner Detector Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html) and [cornerHarris OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#cornerharris) for more information.

Comment: If you use a counter that increases the value inside for loops the value that is returned to me exactly twice. Why?

Comment: if i write:                                                                                                    `for( int j = 0; j < dst_norm.rows ; j++ ){ 
    for( int i = 0; i < dst_norm.cols; i++ ){
        if( (int) dst_norm.at<float>(j,i) > thresh ){
                count+=1;
        }
    }
}`                                                                                                           after the elaboration the value of count is twice.

Comment: If by *twice* you mean `count==2` then it means that it found 2 corners within the given `thresh`. If you expected more then probably you need to decrease your `thresh`.

Comment: Probably I can not explain . If in addition to increasing the counter design a circle around the point I get n circles and the counter that is 2*n

Comment: Print the value of `i` and `j` and see if for each *circle* you are getting two very close values. Might be that it actually draws 2 circles that are very close to each other. So you are getting 2 very close corners that are actually only one.